# Change a git branch in accordance with a pull request's change request?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a github repo to a local repo

```
git clone https://github.com/myOrganization/topOfRepo.git
```

I then created a branch from master, call it `'branch1'`, and made some commits:

```
cd topOfRepo
git checkout -b branch1

echo "additional line of text" >> foo.txt

git commit -m "added text to end of file" foo.txt
```

These were then pushed to the github repo

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch1
```

I then submitted a pull request to merge the branch into master via the "New pull request" button in github.

The [reviewer of the pull request added some "request changes"](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/) to the pull request:

> request changes: Submit feedback that must be addressed before the
>   pull request can be merged.

**What is the standard method for acting on those request changes and providing my subsequent updates into the original pull request?**

Possibilities I can think of, but don't know the consequences, are:

1. Simply commit more changes to branch1 which will somehow make it into the pull request (possibly via another push)
2. Branch off of branch1
3. Create a new branch and new pull request

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to commit changes to your existing branch.

If you want these changes to look like part of the original commits you can use:

1. `git reset HEAD~n` where `n` is the number of commits you want to take back.
2. Make the changes then `git commit -m "updating from feedback"`
3. `git push origin branch1 --force-with-lease`.

Otherwise just make new commits and push!

Either way works, it's really up to how clean your team keeps your pull requests/commit history.

Best git cheat sheet I know of -> https://github.com/k88hudson/git-flight-rules